# What is the complexity of sum of log functions

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I have an algorithm that have the following complexity in big O:

```
log(N) + log(N+1) + log(N+2) + ... + log(N+M)
```

Is it the same as `log(N+M)` since it is the largest element?

OR is it `M*log(N+M)` because it is a sum of `M` elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The important rules to know in order to solve it are:

- Log a + Log b = Log ab, and
- Log a - Log b = Log a/b

---

Add and subtract Log 2, Log 3, ... Log N-1 to the given value.

This will give you Log 2 + Log 3 + ... + Log (N+M) - (Log 2 + Log 3 + ... + Log (N-1))

The first part will compute to *Log ((N+M)!)* and the part after the subtraction sign will compute to *Log ((N-1)!)*

Hence, this complexity comes to *Log ( (N+M)! / (N-1)! )*.

---

**UPDATE** after OP asked another good question in the comment:

> If we have N + N^2 + N^3, it will reduce to just N^3 (the largest element), right? Why we can't apply the same logic here - log(N+M) - largest element?

If we have just two terms that look like Log(N) + Log(M+N), then we can combine them both and say that they will definitely be less than 2 * Log(M+N) and will therefore be O(Log (M+N)).

However, if there is a relation between the number of items being summed and highest value of the item, then the presence of such a relation makes the calculation slightly *not so straightforward.*

For example, the big O of addition of 2 (Log N)'s, is O(Log N), while the big O of summation of N Log N's is not O(Log N) but is O(N * Log N).

In the given summation, the value and the number of total values is dependent on M and N, therefore we cannot put this complexity as Log(M+N), however, we can definitely write it as M * (Log (M+N)).

How? Each of the values in the given summation is less than or equal to Log(M + N), and there are total M such values. Hence the summation of these values will be less than M * (Log (M+N)) and therefore will be O(M * (Log (M+N))).

---

Thus, both answers are correct but O(*Log ( (N+M)! / (N-1)! )*) is a tighter bound.

Comment: Where does the subtraction come in? its not in the OPs question

Comment: But if we have `N + N^2 + N^3`, it will reduce to just `N^3` (the largest element), right?
Why we can't apply the same logic here - `log(N+M)` - largest element?

Comment: @SamerTufail: In the 4th line of my answer: _"Add and subtract Log 2..."_.

Comment: @displayName I read that, but I am not sure why would you subtract? I am just curious.

Comment: @SamerTufail: If I am adding something to the value given by OP, I would have to subtract it from the value too so that OP's original value stays what was originally given to me. I did the addition and subtraction on the whole to get the expression in a form that is solvable.

Comment: @displayName okay I get it, its just another way to reduce the expression. I was more of reducing it by `log(N+k)=log(N(1+k/N)) = log(N) + log(1+k/N)` factoring with N.

Comment: @user8411036: Log of a number is not the same as the number itself. Log of _N_ is, in a way, the number of jumps you would need to do to reach _N_ provided you are able to make double of the previous jump every time. This is why, while N would increase to twice the value, the number of jumps would increase only by 1. That's why Log function behaves differently than the number itself and is a slowly growing function. (1/N)

Comment: @user8411036: For (2/N) of the comment, I thought it was better to update the answer. LMK if there is more confusion.

Comment: It's worth adding that for large N and M, Stirling's approximation says that would be approximately this will be `(N+M) log (N+M) - (N-1) log(N-1) - M + 1`. There are correction terms to this that I'm not evaluating rigorously.

Comment: @jwimberley: You may edit the answer and add that in a new section in the answer. That is a good to know info.

Comment: @displayName Thanks, I did this. I discovered that because the approximation itself has an O-notation bound, the resulting bound using the approximation is of the form O(f) => O(g + O(h)). I turned this into O(g) + O(h), which I believe is correct, but had some doubts about.

Comment: Addition and subtraction are completely redundant here. The result follows directly from the original expression: `log(n)+...log(n+m)=log(n*..n(n+m))=log((n+m)!/(n-1)!)`

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername: The addition and subtraction is the intermediate step of how one reaches from lhs to rhs in the expression you have mentioned in your comment.

Comment: @displayName The transition is trivial and follows straight from the definition of factorial. No need to add unnecessary operations

Answer (score 0):

If M does not depend on N and does not vary then the complexity is `O(log(N))`

For k such as `0 <= k <= M` and `N>=M` and `N>=2`,

```
log(N+k)=log(N(1+k/N)) = log(N) + log(1+k/N) <= log(N) + log(2) 
<= log(N) + log(N) <= 2 log(N)
```

So

```
log(N) + log(N+1) + log(N+2) + ... + log(N+M) <= (M+1)2 log(N)
```

So the complexity in big O is: `log(N)`

To answer your questions:

1) yes because there is a fixed number of elements all less or equal than log(N+M)

2) In fact there are M + 1 elements (from 0 to M)

I specify that O((M+1)log(N+M)) is a O(log(N))